# can anybody explain the difference between " WHERE CAST(SUBSTR(M.year,-4) AS UNSIGNED) < 1970" and "m.year<1970"

Tags: sql, sqlite, substring

I am working with sqlite in goole colab notebook. I have print actor ID who work before 1970. And this is my sql query

```
SELECT  PID FROM M_Cast mc JOIN Movie m on mc.MID=m.MID WHERE m.year< 1970;
```

But it didnt work well for me (I didnt get the accurate result). But when I edit my query to

```
SELECT  PID FROM M_Cast mc JOIN Movie m on mc.MID=m.MID WHERE CAST(SUBSTR(M.year,-4) AS UNSIGNED) < 1970;
```

I get accurate result can anybody explain the difference between these to statements `CAST(SUBSTR(M.year,-4) AS UNSIGNED) < 1970` and `m.year<1970`.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would also help, so it is clear what "different answer" means.  And what is the type of `year`?  In one context it is used as a number and in another as a string.

Answer (score 0):

It would be normal for a column named `year` to store integer 4-digit values, but since your 1st query does not work, this means that this is not the case.

Also because your 2nd query works this means that the last 4 chars of the column contain the year that each movie was made.

So check the column `year` in the table `Movie` for non integer values.
A simple way to do it is by:

```
SELECT * FROM Movie WHERE LENGTH(year) > 4
```